# Name clashing with php include statements?

Tags: php, include

I have a couple of php files that I would like to execute in another "master" file, and I am thinking of using the include statement.

The php files don't have anything OO in them, but each one has variable names that are used in other files (they don't interact except to produce interim text files that are used in the next php file).

Will this prompt name clashes for the variables I put then sequentially in include statements?

Comment: So include files and see what will happen.

Comment: Are they global variables or variables inside functions? Local variables in functions don't conflict with each other.

Comment: If they both assign the same global variables, they'll probably cause conflicts. It would really help if you showed the file contents and explain how they're used by the other scripts. It's hard to answer this in general without seeing them.

Comment: There aren't any user written functions, just a series of statements. The variables are defined as usual, eg $outtext = preg_split($pattern, $between);

Comment: In that case you definitely will experience naming collisions.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like I will have to stick with my current solution... :-(